# How to use the chrome devtools push debug feature?

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, development-environment

The Chrome Browser developer tools have under the application tab an option to test push notifications. I have a registered service worker running that can handle received push notifications but it doesn't receive any from it.
How to test push notifications with it correctly?

Answer (score -2):

go test your code with edge devtools in this case; until chrome is update this bug.